# Java: Generate a list of numbers up without repeating digits?

Tags: java, for-loop, digits

I've seen a programming challenge on an article and while thinking of a way to solve it I figured out that the numbers with no repeating digits might be the first step.

I wrote this on my own and I want to know if this is a good way to generate those numbers!

Here is my code :

```
int limit = 1000;

for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    boolean ignore = false;
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j/=10){
        if(ignore == true) break;
        for(int k = j/10; k > 0; k/=10){
            if(j%10 == k%10){
                ignore = true;
                break;                        
                }                    
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here or on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've only vaguely glanced at your code, and I don't know much Java, but I suspect the correct solution involves [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) and not generating all numbers and filtering out the ones you don't want.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I've read the wiki page. does that mean that there's some kind of formula that generates those numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
        if(check(i))
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
static boolean check(int num){
    int dig=-1;
    boolean flg=true;
    while(num/10 >0){
        if(dig==num%10){
            flg=false;
            break;
        }
        dig=num%10;
        num=num/10;
    }
    if(dig==num)
        flg=false;
    return flg;
}
```